# Adduplex showing error "ad unit configuration error"

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, adduplex

I have a [Windows Phone App](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/message-my-location/72cf2095-a3a4-44b5-94b0-54f7d40d7d25) in which I want to integrate Adduplex. I followed the step [in their page](https://adduplex.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200744262-Universal-SDK-for-XAML-apps-Windows-8-1-Windows-Phone-8-1-installation-and-usage). But when I run the App it is showing "ad unit configuration error".

I have entered these in MainPage.xaml

`xmlns:ad="using:AdDuplex.Universal.Controls.WinPhone.XAML"`

and

```
<ad:AdControl x:Name="adDuplexAd" 
                AppId="72cf2095-a3a4-44b5-94b0-54f7d40d7d25" Margin="0,3,0,0" Canvas.ZIndex="1" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Here is the screenshot of the displayed error:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed the issue. Problem was in the App ID. I had provided Windows Phone store ID instead of App ID provided by ad duplex.

```
<ad:AdControl x:Name="adDuplexAd" 
                AppId="123151" Margin="0,3,0,0" Canvas.ZIndex="1" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

[image]