# WIndows Phone AdMediation control doesn't work with adduplex

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, adduplex

I've integrated the [AdMediation control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn864359.aspx) into my Windows Phone app. This works fine for pubCenter and Google AdMob but not for adduplex.

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn864356.aspx#adduplex), I've used the App ID from adduplex (App key in adduplex dashboard) but I still get a configuration error banner displayed. I found this [blog post](http://dominoc925.blogspot.de/2015/02/how-to-fix-adduplex-ad-unit.html) a few days ago. The post says that I have to use the Ad unit ID (banner in adduplex dashboard) instead of the App key but this it does not work either.

Can somebody who is using the AdMediation control with adduplex explain me the right way?

Answer (score 6):

AdDuplex uses new identifiers since the introduction of [AdDupplex Interstitial ads](http://blog.adduplex.com/2015/02/introducing-interstitial-ads.html).

The `AppId` identifier has been replaced with `AdUnitId` and `AppKey`, but the ad mediator still uses an older version of AdDuplex SDK at the time of writing.

**How to make it work**

The conceptual changes made in AdDuplex are backwards compatible. The `Ad unit ID` is made to be interchangeable with `App ID` used by older SDKs.

So you will just have to set the `App ID` in the Ad Mediator configuration to AdDuplex `Ad unit Id`.

**I still get the ad configuration error**

If you are using an emulator for testing you will still get the ad configuration error. For some reason ad mediator uses a different configuration when run in an emulator. It basically ignores your settings and just uses `0` for `App ID`

There is a workaround for this. The test configuration can be edited in the `AdMediator.config` file, which is added to the project with the ad mediator control. Find the `TestConfiguration` tag and change it's `AppId` value from `0` to your `Ad unit Id`

[image]

Comment: This works for the emulator. I hope this will also work if I submit the XAP package as an update.

Comment: I copied the App ID from BaseConfiguration to the TestConfiguration and it works on the emulator but it doesn't work on the real device.

Comment: Yes, I haven't deleted the BaseConfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the ID which you've provided, whether it's the `Windows Phone Store ID` or the App ID provided by `adduplex`. Found a workaround [here](http://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2015/02/how-to-fix-adduplex-ad-unit.html) too.

[Adduplex showing error "ad unit configuration error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850498/)

Comment: I double checked it and tested it with App key and Ad unit but it does not work!

Comment: This is really strange. If I implement the adduplex control manually and set the *App Id* property to my Ad unit ID, then it works! Only with the AdMediation control it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this exact same problem changing the config in the ***project*** to the ***Ad Unit Id*** (the 5-6 digit number).

What did not work for me was only changing the config in Dev Center > AdMediator.

So you probably need an update for your app with the updated Ad Unit Id.