# Windows Phone 8.1, admediator and adduplex

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, adduplex

I implemented the adMediator control in my xaml Windows Phone 8.1 app with pubcenter, adduplex and smatoo configured.

I have a problem with my adduplex ad on device. I have a banner with "ad unit configuration error, please verify your configuration".

The message is clear... But I don't find a solution...

I found this article:
http://dominoc925.blogspot.fr/2015/02/how-to-fix-adduplex-ad-unit.html

I saw that I set the wrong id for adduplex (label title in visual studio talk about app and not ad), so I made the modification but with no success, always the same error...

Did I forget something to configure? Someone would have an idea or already had this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Refer to my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149958/windows-phone-admediation-control-doesnt-work-with-adduplex/29162614#29162614

Comment: Thank you. Apparently all was ok in my configuration, two days later the adduplex ad appear correctly... It was maybe due to a validation time of my application on adduplex time, I don't know...